# Does $f \in o(g)$ imply $g^{-1} \in o(f^{-1})$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

**Question**

Suppose $f,g : \mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R_+$ are increasing, bijective functions such that $f(x) \in o\big(g(x)\big)$ as $x \to \infty$.

Does it then follow that $g^{-1}(x) \in o\big(f^{-1}(x)\big)$ as $x \to \infty$?

---

**Thoughts**

This is true in the special case $g \equiv \text{id}$, since
$$
\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{y}{f^{-1}(y)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{f^{-1}(f(x))} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 0.
$$
Therefore, $x \in o\big(f^{-1}(x)\big)$ as $x \to \infty$.

But that trick only works above, since $\text{id}^{-1} \equiv \text{id}$.

Still, it seems that the statement ought to hold generally -- especially when sketching examples.

Trying a similar strategy in the general case yields
$$
\lim_{y \to \infty} \frac{g^{-1}(x)}{f^{-1}(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g^{-1}(f(x))}{x} \leq \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g^{-1}(g(x))}{x} = 1 
$$
Intuitively, though, it seems $f$ would be "strong" enough to make $x \in o(g^{-1} \circ f)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, take $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(x) = e^{2x}$, so that $g^{-1}(x) = \frac12\log x$ and $f^{-1}(x) = \log x$.

Comment: Do you know if this would hold if we also demanded that $f(x), g(x) \in o(x)$? I haven't been able to show that, but it seems plausible.

Comment: No: geometrically you should be able to convince yourself that there are still counterexamples by drawing step functions for $f$ and $g$ (which could be slightly perturbed to yield continuous strictly increasing functions that are therefore invertible).